# Text Processing - Two text files: read block lines from one file and append it after a string in another text file

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I need to merge two text files that have fixed block of lines into one.

### How can I do it?

```
bridge-domain AAAA
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
!
port-down flush disable
!
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop  <---
```

after this line I need to append a block of lines from another text file like this:

```
interface Bundle-Ether AAAAA
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
!
```

---

So basically I need to read every 6 lines from text2.txt and append it every 12 lines into text1.txt

Desidered output:

```
bridge-domain AAAA
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
!
port-down flush disable
!
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether AAAAA
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
!
bridge-domain BBBB
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
!
port-down flush disable
!
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether BBBB
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
!
```

etc...until the end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` script with more extensive test samples.

`input.1.txt`

```
bridge-domain AAAA
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
!
port-down flush disable
! -1
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop  1
! 1.1
bridge-domain BBBB
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
port-down flush disable
! -2
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop 2
! 2.1
bridge-domain CCC
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
port-down flush disable
! -3
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop 3
! 3.1
```

`input.2.txt`

```
interface Bundle-Ether AAAAA
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! AAAA section end
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether BBBB
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! BBBB section end
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether CCCC
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! CCCC section end
```

`script.awk`

```
FNR == NR {    # read insertion paragraph from file 1
    inpSectn = inpSectn $0; # accumlate input lines in inpSectn
    if (NR % 6 == 0) {  # if 6th line add section to array
        sectnArr[++arrCount] = inpSectn; # add inpSectn to ordered array
        inpSectn = "";  # reset inpSectn
    }
    next;      # skip further processing till all file 1 is consumed.
}
1              # output current input line.
FNR % 12 == 0 {   # every 12th line in file 2
    print sectnArr[++arrIdx]; # output section
}
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.2.txt input.1.txt
```

output:

```
bridge-domain AAAA
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
!
port-down flush disable
! -1
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop  1
interface Bundle-Ether AAAAA
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! AAAA section end
! 1.1
bridge-domain BBBB
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
port-down flush disable
! -2
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop 2
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether BBBB
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! BBBB section end
! 2.1
bridge-domain CCC
mac
aging
time 3
!
limit
maximum 12
notification both
port-down flush disable
! -3
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop 3
igmp snooping profile igmp-snoop
interface Bundle-Ether CCCC
dhcp ipv4 snoop profile
static-mac-address 0001
static-mac-address 0002
! CCCC section end
! 3.1
```

Comment: That's missing the ORS in `inpSectn = inpSectn $0;` and will print a blank line if /when the number of blocks in input.2.txt is less than the number in input.1.txt. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56868537/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '12~12{:a;R file2' -e 'x;s/^/x/;/x\{6\}/!{x;ba};z;x}' file1
```

This reads sequentially from file2 for six lines every 12 lines in file1. It uses a counter in the hold space which is reset after the sixth line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        rec = rec $0 ORS
        if ( (FNR % 6) == 0 ) {
            recs[FNR/6] = rec
            rec = ""
        }
        next
    }
    { print }
    (FNR % 12) == 0 ) { printf "%s", recs[FNR/12] }
' file2 file1
```

or if you prefer brief and cryptic (since you asked for a sed solution to something that's not simply s/old/new):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{r=r$0"\n";if(!FNR%6){s[++x]=r;r="";next}!(FNR%12){$0=$0 s[++y]}1' file2 file1
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! Lots of ways to do it as I see. I used the awk script but also Ed Morton and potong methods were ok!
Thank you.

Comment: as you have 15 reputation score, you are allowed to upvote the contributors.